# Как через vk_api получить id рандомного участника беседы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Как с помощью vk_api или других библиотек записать в переменную id пользователя?

Answer (score 0):

Когда вам пришел `event` из `VkBotLongPoll().listen()` вы можете просто записать id пользователя: `user_id = event.object['message']['from_id']`